# suddenly get this error io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepdefinitions.BasicStepDefs

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

My project used to work properly but suddenly i get this error.Code works at another computer but the very same code does not work on my machine.By the way i'm sure code is working cause i pull it from github and tried on another pc.

04:15:54.290 [main]
INFO stepdefinitions.hook.Hooks - ---------------Test Automation has started------------
04:15:54.292 [main]
INFO  stepdefinitions.hook.Hooks - Test Scenario : Validate that passenger flight information
04:15:54.293 [main]
INFO  stepdefinitions.hook.Hooks - Browser type ----> chrome

Step failed
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepdefinitions.BasicStepDefs
at
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".your-reservation"}

[my project plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g93wo.png)

I tried to pull again but nothing changed.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Format the error dump, and include enough code for others to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the provided stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".your-reservation"}
```

Somewhere in your code you are looking for the element with the class 'your-reservation', but it cannot be found not found.

Check the 'getNumberOfReservation' method in the 'HotelConfirmationPage' class.

You are interacting with the mentioned element in the 'BaseStep' class.